# RSpec tests on has_secure_password strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm developing a RoR 4 application, following Michael Hartl's tutorial.

When implementing the user authentication tests, everything goes fine. I have a few more mandatory fields than in the book, here is the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :playground_id, presence: true
  validates :default_playground_id, presence: true
  validates :active_from, presence: true
  validates :active_to, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :login, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 100 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :directory_id, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :first_name, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :password_digest, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :remember_token, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :created_by, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :updated_by, length: { maximum: 30 }

  has_secure_password

end
```

Here are the tests related to the authentication process only:

```
###USER6 to test that password is correctly managed
  describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(playground_id: 0, default_playground_id: 0, last_name: "Other User", login: "OTHER_USR", 
    email: "other@example.com", active_from: "2013-01-01", active_to: "2113-01-01", is_admin: 1.zero?,
                 password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
  end

### end
```

Yes, it works fine! Here is the result of running the tests:

```
Failures:

  1) User model validation: with a password that's too short should be invalid
     Failure/Error: it { should be_invalid }
       expected invalid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:171:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.28647 seconds
37 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:171 # User model validation: with a password that's too short should be invalid

Randomized with seed 18843
```

**Now, if I add the password length validation in the User model:**

```
...
  validates :created_by, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :updated_by, length: { maximum: 30 }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

Running the tests returns errors about undefined authenticate method, and even brakes tests that are not related to authentication:

```
...
  5) User model validation: return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }
     NoMethodError:

       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass

     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:183:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:186:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.29266 seconds

37 examples, 5 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:51 # User model validation: availability of mandatory fields should be valid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:135 # User model validation: when email format is valid should be valid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:179 # User model validation: return value of authenticate method with valid password 
...
```

**What is the reason for this, how can I solve it ?**

Thanks for your help,

Fred

PS : the gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.4.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

# gem for dev and test only
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.14.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.33.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is dificult to say without viewing all code.

I think the problem is here

```
before { @user.save }
let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }
```

when you add validation for password length then variable `@user` becomes NOT valid. It means that found_user is nil (the record was not saved and can not be found). And then you get `undefined method 'authenticate' for nil:NilClass`.

I suggest when you really want create records use `save!` and `create!` in tests - if there are some problems you will see it immediately.

The same reason can be for another tests which are not connected with authentication but which trying to save invalid records in DB.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right : the password initialisation at the beginning of the whole test was too short, and any attempt to save would fail. All tests now fit for purpose !